# How to inherit IDisposable in GenericRepo of TEntity

Tags: c#, inheritance, idisposable

I have a generic repository whose signature is

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
```

Can I inherit IDsposable for the GenericRepository? because no matter where I put the inherit IDisposable it either errs, or it makes the class I'm inserting IDisposable, NOT the repo.

Comment: Interfaces are implemented, not inherited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax would be:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable where TEntity : class {
     // TODO: Implement a Dispose() method.
}
```

Note that you have to implement a `Dispose()` method.